# Particular nodes are missing from node editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I am looking for the [Mapping Node](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/types/vector.html#mapping-node) but it is not available under the Vector nodes menu or any other menu. I have Blender 2.77 which cooresponds with the manual version in the above link.

[image]

I also cannot find the Texture Coordinate or Gradient Texture.

Likely I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Wrong node tree type

Blender has three built-in different [node tree types](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/introduction.html#node-tree-types): *Material*, *Composite* and *Textures*. They have some nodes in common, and some not. The ones you are looking for belong to the second group.

[image]

All the nodes you mentioned belong to the Material node editor, you can see that from the path of the page in the manual you linked:

[image]

Just switch from the *Composite* type editor to *Material* type editor and you should be able to find them.

Comment: Brilliant. I have much to learn.