# Node editor - I do not have Diffuse BSDF node available. Why?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Being really new to rendering things, I have little knowledge no how things work in Blender (texturing/rendering wise).

Watching Firechild's tutorial on how to create a golden ring.... he does have Diffuse BSDF and Image Texture nodes available.... which I do not... (there is only 'Image' node)

Downloaded some model from Blendswap and these nodes are there....

My question is what exactly affects the selection of nodes available to a particular scene? Does it has anything to do with the materials/settings used?

Thanks for your reply!

Cheers

Comment: If you're using Cycles, I can't see any reason that these nodes shouldn't be available. If you press Shift+A, what options are you given?

Comment: Maybe you are in the wrong node tree type: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53336/particular-nodes-are-missing-from-node-editor/53338#53338. Can you add a screenshot of your node editor and scene?