# Node Shader and Principled BSDF not in the node list.

Tags: node-editor

I was excited about the Principled BSDF but it did not appear on the new download 2.78c. Along with this I was following a tutorial and discovered that when I hit shift A for adding nodes that the shader was not in the list.

[image]

Comment: It's only available in the test build of 2.79 - https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79  and maybe the 2.8 Project though I haven't checked.  It's not an official release yet.

Comment: Also found in the daily build bot at www.blender.builder.org

Comment: possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53336/particular-nodes-are-missing-from-node-editor

Comment: I have to wonder what tutorial authors are irresponsibly neglecting to explain when features are only available in test builds...if that is the case.

Answer (score 5):

Besides being in the wrong version of blender ( for the Principled BSDF you need version 2.79, currently only available as a [test build](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79)), you are looking at the compositing nodes, not the ones for materials.

[image]

Comment: Big thanks. This was very helpful and solved the problem. I am glad it was something easy.