# Where is the principles BSDF shader?

Tags: shaders

I just watched Blender Guru's video on the new-ish Priciples BSDF shader. My current version of Blender is 2.78c. I don't know where to find the release which has Principles BSDF. On the Blender latest releases, they still say 2.78c. What version has Principles, and where can I download it?

Thanks, Phil

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node Shader and Principled BSDF not in the node list.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82557/node-shader-and-principled-bsdf-not-in-the-node-list)

Comment: get the latest builds here: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/ or here (at the bottom of the page): https://builder.blender.org/download/

Answer (score 2):

It is part of the upcoming 2.79 release and unavailable in previous versions of Blender.

It is not available as a stable release yet and you are recommended to await for the official 2.79 version (available **When It's Ready™**) to use it, unless you understand the risks of using pre-release testing software.

Comment: @PhilipKP you can try the build versions. You might find a few bugs, but they are functional enough to try some of the new features.