# Noise texture node is not available

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes, color

I am creating a shockwave similar to that in a youtube tutorial, and I want to make it multiple colors (Purple and red), but it seems the noise texture node is not available in compositing, which is EXACTLY what I need.

[image]

Shockwave tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNLOjw5HYc&t=1829s
However, since it's not at my disposal, I need another way of getting this result. Anyone know how to do this? Or, if there  is a way to get access to the noise texture itself, I'd appreciate that as well. Anything helps. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53336/particular-nodes-are-missing-from-node-editor

Comment: make sure that you are using the node editor in texture mode, not as compositor. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZoSY.png

Comment: If I am understanding what you say, you could set up a second render layer with a plane facing the camera, with an emissive shader with its color mapped to a noise texture, render that and the use that render layer in compositing, do note that this will only produce "2D" noise, not exactly sure why you need noise in the compositor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Particular nodes are missing from node editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53336/particular-nodes-are-missing-from-node-editor)

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Basically, I'm hoping to add noise in the compositor so that I can have two different colors within this shockwave.

Answer (score 1):

check the bottom of the frame you captured, he is not editing the Composition nodes, he is just adding the noise texture to the material so the strands would have color variation.

Comment: I understand that, and that is also what I am trying to achieve. Unfortunately, the noise texture node is not available in compositor, so I need another way to achieve this.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't need the compositor. You need to add the noise in the Material Node Editor

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84546/adding-random-noise-to-rendered-images