# How to get an evenly distributed noise on compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transforms, shaders

I want to generate a random value for each pixel in the compositor, I tried the noise texture but it gets lower values in average instead of 0.5. 50% of the pixels are completely black.
Far to be enough to build random vectors.
[image]

How can I get TRUE randomness on compositor?

Comment: Read @bertmoog 's answer in this link https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84546/adding-random-noise-to-rendered-images/84730#84730

Comment: That's not exactly what I want.
The problem is that the noise texture do not create a statically neutral noise.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a blur of two pixels gives a nice distribution throughout the tone range.

[image]

**Edit**

This is custom color noise setup.

[image]