# Add color noise to render

Tags: compositing-nodes

I mostly do video compositing, where I insert objects into a tracked clip. I want it to look as realistic as possible and on closer inspection one can see that the original footage has noise (red, green and blue) but the rendered objects don't. Is there a way to fake that in cycles?

It's supposed to be some sort of hologram table. Nothing fancy, just for testing so far.

[image: One frame of the clip. Noise visible when zooming in.]

Comment: There is a link in this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/physical-iridescence-in-cycles) that gives an example of color noise at a very fine detail. I made a comment within the linked question, with a link to a blend file that I used to try and mimic that, It essentially adds color noise.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84546/adding-random-noise-to-rendered-images

Answer (score 2):

You can use texture and color mix node to add noise, same way you would add it to the material. Can find answers/videos from quick search through google even from this stackexchange ([link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84546/adding-random-noise-to-rendered-images)) - I would look into 2nd answer because with the first one your noise won't change through frames. If you want colored noise you can use color ramp between texture and color mix node (and maybe change mix mode?).