# Compositing issue when adding gaussian noise to image

Tags: compositing-nodes

I need to add random gaussian noise to images rendered with EEVEE. I thought about python coding this at the pixel level but I'm having issues with color spaces, so I came back to the compositor to get it.

I generated my noise and want to add this to the rendered image. While the noise appears on the rendered object, the background does not get any noise. I'm probably forgetting to check a parameter but can't have it, maybe related to depth ?

here is the noise image [image] and there the very simple node system [image]. The result after compositing is here [image]
To check what's happening, I also did a difference with the noise image again and obtain the initial rendered image, meaning that although the noise does not appear in the background of the image, it is still computed and removed.

Any clue of what's missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: If you "add", you are making things brighter. But the background is already white, the top of the scale. You might want to subtract or multiply the noise.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84546/adding-random-noise-to-rendered-images

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Pullup, I'm a bit confused. The background being grey, so it seems there's still room for a few levels for an increase so I should see the dots. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I would try making the noise much larger to test the effect of your nodes.

Comment: Thanks @3pointedit, tried that, but that does not seem to provide good results either..