# Missing Noise Texture Node in Material View

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate. I have checked similar posts and their alleged duplicates, but have not seen/understood any answers (EG: [Noise texture node is not available](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82569/noise-texture-node-is-not-available/82590#82590)).

I am following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2XjdzzWCqI @ 11:54) and it would appear that I am missing a vanilla node called Noise Texture, used to add "random" colour variety into textures.
I have pressed Shift+A to bring up the node search menu and not found a Noise Texture. I have selected the Materials button, so that alone cannot be the issue.

This is in Blender 2.79b.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.[image: Screen of my issue - after Shift+A>Search...]

Answer (score 1):

You need to press <kbd>A</kbd> (Add) to have access to the node *Search* option, not <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. Anyway, to create a *Noise Texture*, press <kbd>A</kbd> > *Texture* > *Noise Texture*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The original screen shot I sent is of the "add" search. Instead of there being a noise texture option, it's just blank.

Any advice on locating the missing node would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: oh ok sorry, weird because it works correctly on my computer  :/

Comment: All good. I think it might work correctly on every computer but mine. I have no idea what is different about my Blender.

Comment: @Jermu Are you still set to *Cycles* render engine? If you've swapped to Blender Render in your efforts to find the node then the search won't find it any more as it's not a valid node in that render engine. Swap back to 'Cycles' (the Engine field in the top bar) and you should be able to find it.