# Nodes For quick smoke not showing

Tags: node-editor

So i'm following a guide by blender guru and i'm following his exact steps. when he goes into the node editor it shows the nodes for the quick smoke. when i do it its just blank. help?

Comment: Before you click on "Quick Smoke" you have to switch to "Cycles Render" for render engine to create the material automatically. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53336/particular-nodes-are-missing-from-node-editor and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/why-does-my-material-panel-look-different