# Can't find the Material Output in Cycles!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I can't find both Diffuse BDSF and Material Output, i am in fact in cycles render. Here is an image to show [image]

Help would be highly appreciated since i can't really do anything without it at the moment.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53336/particular-nodes-are-missing-from-node-editor https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91812/why-am-i-missing-nodes-in-the-add-node-menu

Comment: Thank you Duarte :D